# Python-Facebook API: How do I get the profile_ids of all the people who have liked my recent posts on facebook using Python Facebook API?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

These are some things that python-facebook graph API tells me:

**Methods**

1. `get_objects`: 
   Returns all of the given objects from the graph as a dict. Each given ID maps to an object. 
   Parameters: 
   `ids` – A list containing IDs for multiple resources. 
    
   Example:

   ```
   post_`ids = ['post_id_1', 'post_id_2']
   posts = graph.get_objects(ids=post_ids)
   # Each given id maps to an object.
   for post_id i`n post_ids:
      print(posts[post_id]['created_time'])
   ```
2. `get_connections`:
   Returns all connections for a given object as a dict.
   Parameters:
   `id` – A string that is a unique ID for that particular resource.
   `connection_name` - A string that specifies the connection or edge between objects, e.g., feed, friends, groups, likes, posts. If left empty, `get_connections` will simply return the authenticated user’s basic information.

   Example:
   Get all of the authenticated user's friends

   ```
   friends = graph.get_connections(id='me', connection_name='friends')
   # Get all the comments from a post
   comments = graph.get_connections(id='post_id', connection_name='comments')
   ```
3. `put_like`:
   Writes a like to the given object.
    
   Parameters:
   `object_id` - A string that is a unique id for a particular resource. 
   Example:

   ```
   graph.put_like(object_id='comment_id')
   ```

Source: http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

So, How do I get the posts that are recently liked (`get_objects`) and the profile ids of people who have liked those posts (`get_connections`) and put a like on the friends posts who had liked my posts (`put_like`)?

Answer (score -1):

You should try using JSON and working with the data you get from there, you can import json on python and makes the request via this library, it would be much easier.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Should I use JSON encoding and decoding? if yes then how?

Thanks!